# X-Files episode with a worm creature travelling through drain pipes

Tags: episode-identification, the-x-files

All I can remember of this particular episode is the monster;

- It was a humanoid / worm-creature that traveled through drain pipes.
- I'm pretty sure it gained access to people's homes through their toilets.
- I remember thinking the creature was especially creepy.

Comment: That was called the Chamber of Secrets.

Comment: When I read the question I immediately thought of Eugene from Tooms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is  "[The Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Host_(The_X-Files))".

The *X-Files* wiki identifies the protagonist as a mutated flukeworm:

> Mulder and Scully investigate a body found in sewage after being
>   reassigned to different departments. Their inquiry results in the
>   discovery of a bizarre fluke-like man—the product of the Chernobyl
>   disaster—that soon goes on a rampage in the sewers of New Jersey.

[image: weird, ugly, worm-like monster]

Comment: God... Yeah that's the guy! What a looker!!

Comment: That is truly terrifying.

Comment: I saw this as a re-run when I was 8 or 9, terrified the crap out of me so much. To this day my stomach knots and I get chills whenever I remember it.

Comment: This was the only episode of the X Files that I had nightmares of when I was a child. Still freaks me out.

Comment: Great. Should not have clicked on this. I have routine nightmares of this very episode still as an adult.

Comment: You folks should refrain from watching "Home" (S4E2). That makes Flukeman look like the cute monsters from "Hotel Transylvania".

Comment: @JCCyC - word. That was the most horrifying episode of X-Files by far.

Comment: And that's its flattering Facebook image.

Answer (score 3):

It was [Tooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooms) - they made 2 episodes with the character Tooms, one with the same name, the first was [Squeeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_(The_X-Files)). Or possibly [The Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Host_(The_X-Files))

Comment: No I don't think it was. The creature I remember was much more _worm-like_.

Comment: Just added The Host as another option. This is The X-Files - there were a few ;)

Comment: Oh, I posted my answer without seeing that you had edited. The Host is a better fit to the question, yes. (I should have spent less time on Wikipedia, but you know how it goes.)

Answer (score 1):

In episode "Agua Mala" (S06E13, 1999) there is a worm-like creature, it changes consistency from liquid to jelly and viceversa.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0751069):

> As a hurricane bears down on the Florida coast, the agents search for a sea monster that Arthur Dales believes is responsible for the disappearance of a couple and their son.

[This website](https://xfilesbodycount.blogspot.it/2009/10/season-6-episode-13-agua-mala.html) has a more detailed summary and a picture of the monster:

[image: worm like creature]